# Trying to echo a string in a search box

Tags: php, string, textbox, echo

I am trying to `echo` a string in a search box. However so far it only *`echos`* the first word of the string.

```
require 'search.php';
$searchQuery = $_GET['searchText'] ;
echo $searchQuery;//prints "this is a test"
$search = new Search();
$search->run($searchQuery);
.
.
<input name="searchText" type="text" id="searchText" size=70 value = <?php echo $searchQuery; // prints "this"?> />
```

Comment: You can't just directly echo that stuff.. what if my query is `"><script type="text/javascript">...`

Comment: don't forget to sanitize `$_GET` variable before use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you don't have quotes around it, so what you're actually outputting is

```
<input ... value = this is a test />
```

So it's assigning the first token as the "value" property.
Try this:

```
<input ... value="<?php echo $searchQuery; ?>" />
```

Comment: No problem, we all miss little things now and then!

Comment: To the -1 vote: Please give a reason or remove your vote.  Submitter already commented that this answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding quotes:

```
<input name="searchText" type="text" id="searchText" size="70" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($searchQuery); ?>"/>
```

As [Esailija pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729141/trying-to-echo-a-string-a-search-box/11729463#11729463), escaping properly with `htmlspecialchars()` is a better solution and will ensure it prints the value correctly whatever the search may be.

Comment: This is coming directly from `$_GET`

Comment: So you down vote every other *correct* answer in other to clean up the Question page. Nicely done :) I would delete my answer when I want though.

Comment: Well, they are only half-correct. What if the query simply has quotes? then it will stop at some word again. This is without even considering the XSS. It's pretty easy to make them full-correct, so if people edit I will remove them.

Comment: Of course I understand. In this case he was just looking for a quick solution, not a special scenario, but programmers do have different flairs :)

Comment: Btw I also want to say that it's not a special situation. Any searchbox worth using will support quotes for exact matches. Google, stackoverflow search etc.. ;p

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes around the value of the 'value' attribute, as such:

```
<input name="searchText" type="text" id="searchText" size=70 value="<?php echo $searchQuery; // prints "this"?>" />
```

Otherwise this is what will render:

```
<input name="searchText" type="text" id="searchText" size=70 value = this is some sentent />
```

which defines value of the attribute named 'value' to be "this", and then creates more (meaningless) attributes "is", "some" and "sentence" which have no values. Quotes are important! You should also probably quote your size variable although it's not important in this case.

Also note that not inspecting and/or sanitizing the GET variable leaves you open to HTML/Javascript injection attacks -- if I provided the value `word onClick='doSomething();'` as the GET variable value, I could execute javascript on the client. If this were rendered as part of a comments section of a website as such, I could potentially inject other client's machines with arbitrary javascript.

[EDIT]

You can accomplish this by using `htmlspecialchars` as pointed out by Esailija. For more information about common web vulnerabilities and the reason for sanitizing GET variables, perhaps you should check out [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: oh how I love anonymous downvotes... any reasoning? Do you disagree with injectionability? Would you like an example? Regardless, it's only additional information and my answer still addresses the question.

Comment: Well I didn't want to have same conversation in every answer on the page. You can read my comments on Chibueze Opata's answer. It's incredibly common to use quotes with searches which would break this and show only some of the words again. Apart from not being correct, they have an XSS vulnerability. So they are not only "not useful" but downright harmful. Want to make a meta discussion about it?

Comment: Apparently Esailija downvoted every other answer but his, from what I've gathered in the other comments.

Comment: @Esailija yes, and I both answered his question and explained the security vulnerability posed by not sanitizing his GET variable. Did you READ my answer or any of the others? Not only was the question already answered, but you were late to the show. Don't just downvote because you think your answer is better... from the SO FAQ: `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.`

Comment: FWIW, I downvoted and waited quite a while for the edits to come in. I didn't event want to make an answer. Anyway, the point is not XSS but flat out not working if the queries have quotes (which is normal).

Comment: Fair enough. While I disagree with your attention-getting mechanism, I see that it is effective. I see your point about the quotes/escaping in addition to the fact that XSS is possible, and in retrospect simply telling him to escape w/ htmlspecialchars is the simplest, most concise and proper answer. So, apologies for my terseness in response to your perceived asbergers-ness :) But one thing I do avoid here is always giving the simple answer "Just use this function, like so" because the asker may not understand what sanitization is or what `htmlspecialchars` does. S/he probably will now, hehe.

Comment: I just don't understand why you would write a paragraph about the vulnerability issues but still leave the code fragile. The only place to html escape the value is just before the value is output, so the op cannot do it anywhere else other than this snippet. I cannot remove my downvote before the post has been edited, so it might as well be a tiny function call addition ;p

Comment: Because I don't want to give him the answer to plug and chug, I want to say "this is dangerous" and not give a one-line solution so s/he has to do some work on their own (otherwise similar questions will probably be asked again). I want him/her to know WHY is this dangerous, to understand when it applies, when it doesn't, etc. Anyway, added a reference to the function and a link to open source web application security project, which I think is good for newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input name="searchText" type="text" id="searchText" size="70" value="<?php echo $searchQuery; ?>" />
```